# This table has the correct column and row headers, and the correct first column, but the rest of the table gets messed up (not worried about spacing)

Tags: python

```
# Function to calculate the Heat Index
def calculate_heat_index(temperature, relative_humidity):
    c1 = -42.379
    c2 = 2.04901523
    c3 = 10.14333127
    c4 = -0.22475541
    c5 = -6.83783e-03
    c6 = -5.481717e-02
    c7 = 1.22874e-03
    c8 = 8.5282e-04
    c9 = -1.99e-06

    heat_index = (
        c1
        + c2 * temperature
        + c3 * relative_humidity
        + c4 * temperature * relative_humidity
        + c5 * temperature ** 2
        + c6 * relative_humidity ** 2
        + c7 * temperature ** 2 * relative_humidity
        + c8 * temperature * relative_humidity ** 2
        + c9 * temperature ** 2 * relative_humidity ** 2
    )

    return heat_index
#def r_step(temperature):
first_value = 70
last_value = 90
num_values = 8
step = (last_value - first_value) / (num_values - 1)
second_value = 50
boo_value = 85
num2_values = 10
step2 = (boo_value - second_value) / (num2_values - 1)
# Print the table header
print("Heat Index")
print(" RH \\ T ", end="\t")
for t in range(8):
    value = first_value + t * step

    print(f"{value:.1f}   ", end="\t")
print("   \n -------", end="\t")

#seperator jawns
for _ in range(8):
    print("-----", end="\t")
print()
print()
# Print the table values
for x in range(10):
    value2 = second_value + x * step2
    print(f"  {value2:.1f}   ", end="\t")
    for temp in range(8):
        heat_index = calculate_heat_index(first_value, value2)
        print(f"{heat_index:.1f}", end="\t")
        value2 += step
    print()
```

What I got:

```
Heat Index
 RH \ T     70.0    72.9    75.7    78.6    81.4    84.3    87.1    90.0       
 -------    -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   

  50.0      76.9    76.9    76.9    76.9    76.9    76.9    76.9    76.9    
  53.9      76.6    76.6    76.6    76.6    76.6    76.6    76.6    76.6    
  57.8      76.2    76.2    76.2    76.2    76.2    76.2    76.2    76.2    
  61.7      75.6    75.6    75.6    75.6    75.6    75.6    75.6    75.6    
  65.6      74.9    74.9    74.9    74.9    74.9    74.9    74.9    74.9    
  69.4      74.0    74.0    74.0    74.0    74.0    74.0    74.0    74.0    
  73.3      73.0    73.0    73.0    73.0    73.0    73.0    73.0    73.0    
  77.2      71.8    71.8    71.8    71.8    71.8    71.8    71.8    71.8    
  81.1      70.5    70.5    70.5    70.5    70.5    70.5    70.5    70.5    
  85.0      69.0    69.0    69.0    69.0    69.0    69.0    69.0    69.0
```

What I was expecting:

```
Heat Index
 RH \ T    70.0   72.9   75.7   78.6   81.4   84.3   87.1   90.0
-------   -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
  50.0     76.9   77.0   77.9   79.6   82.2   85.5   89.6   94.6
  53.9     76.6   76.8   77.9   79.9   82.7   86.4   91.0   96.4
  57.8     76.2   76.6   77.9   80.1   83.3   87.4   92.5   98.4
  61.7     75.6   76.2   77.8   80.3   83.9   88.5   94.1  100.6
  65.6     74.9   75.7   77.6   80.6   84.6   89.7   95.8  103.0
  69.4     74.0   75.1   77.4   80.8   85.3   90.9   97.7  105.5
  73.3     73.0   74.5   77.1   81.0   86.0   92.3   99.7  108.3
  77.2     71.8   73.7   76.8   81.2   86.8   93.7  101.8  111.2
  81.1     70.5   72.8   76.5   81.4   87.7   95.2  104.1  114.2
  85.0     69.0   71.9   76.1   81.6   88.6   96.8  106.5  117.5
```

Comment: Please provide a clearer description than "*gets messed up*" and just dumping code. For example: What is this table supposed to be? How are the column values supposed to be calculated? What was your plan/algorithm for the code?

Answer (score 0):

> *"This table has the correct column and row headers, and the correct first column, but the rest of the table gets messed up ..."*

I encountered a similar problem when using the same data-set for *Fahrenheit* values.

Switching to the *Celsius* data-set appears to work correctly.

*[Wikipedia – Heat index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index)*.

```py
def c(f): return (f - 32) * (5 / 9)
def f(c): return (c * 1.8) + 32

def heat_index(T, R):
    c = [-8.78469475556, 1.61139411, 2.33854883889,
         -.14611605, -.012308094, -.0164248277778,
         2.211732e-3, 7.2546e-4, -3.582e-6]
    return c[0] \
        + (c[1] * T) \
        + (c[2] * R) \
        + (c[3] * T * R) \
        + (c[4] * (T ** 2)) \
        + (c[5] * (R ** 2)) \
        + (c[6] * (T ** 2) * R) \
        + (c[7] * T * (R ** 2)) \
        + (c[8] * (T ** 2) * (R ** 2))

x, xn, n = 27, 43, 16
y, ym, m = 40, 100, 13
i = (xn - x) / (n - 1)
j = (ym - y) / (m - 1)

ts = [(x + (e * i)) for e in range(n)]
rs = [(y + (e * j)) for e in range(m)]
print(' ' * 6, end=' ')
for t in ts: print(f'{f(t):>6.1f}', end=' ')
print()
for r in rs:
    print(f'{r:>6.1f}', end=' ')
    for t in ts:
        hi = heat_index(t, r)
        if hi < 54:
            print(f'{f(hi):>6.1f}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Output

```
         80.6   82.5   84.4   86.4   88.3   90.2   92.1   94.0   96.0   97.9   99.8  101.7  103.6  105.6  107.5  109.4 
  40.0   80.4   81.9   83.7   85.9   88.3   91.0   94.0   97.2  100.8  104.7  108.8  113.2  118.0  123.0  128.3 
  45.0   80.8   82.6   84.6   87.0   89.8   92.8   96.2   99.9  104.0  108.3  113.0  118.0  123.4  129.1 
  50.0   81.4   83.3   85.7   88.4   91.5   95.0   98.8  103.0  107.5  112.5  117.7  123.4 
  55.0   81.9   84.2   86.9   90.0   93.5   97.4  101.7  106.4  111.6  117.1  123.0 
  60.0   82.5   85.2   88.3   91.8   95.8  100.2  105.0  110.3  116.0  122.2  128.8 
  65.0   83.2   86.3   89.8   93.8   98.2  103.2  108.6  114.5  120.9  127.7 
  70.0   83.9   87.4   91.4   96.0  101.0  106.5  112.6  119.1  126.2 
  75.0   84.7   88.7   93.2   98.3  104.0  110.1  116.9  124.2 
  80.0   85.5   90.1   95.2  100.9  107.2  114.1  121.5 
  85.0   86.4   91.6   97.3  103.7  110.7  118.3  126.5 
  90.0   87.3   93.1   99.6  106.7  114.4  122.8 
  95.0   88.3   94.8  102.0  109.9  118.4  127.6 
 100.0   89.3   96.6  104.5  113.2  122.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the heat index article and debugging your code, what was at issue was which values were being incremented and which values were being redundantly incremented in the final "for" loop.

This lead to the following refactored code at the end of the program.

```
# Print the table values
for x in range(10):
    value2 = second_value + x * step2
    print(f"  {value2:.1f}   ", end="\t")
    for temp in range(8):
        heat_index = calculate_heat_index(first_value + temp * step, value2)    # Need to increcment the temperature
        print(f"{heat_index:.1f}", end="\t")
        #value2 += step - this is a redundant step
    print()
```

The bits to note were:

- The temperature value as an input parameter to the "calculate_heat_index" function needed to be incremented by the step value each time it was being called.
- Since the incrementation of the relative humidity value was already being incremented in the outer "for" loop, having the the line of code "value2 += step" was being redundant.

With that, following is the test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/HeatIndex$ python3 HeatIndex.py 
Heat Index
 RH \ T     70.0    72.9    75.7    78.6    81.4    84.3    87.1    90.0       
 -------    -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   

  50.0      76.9    77.0    77.9    79.6    82.2    85.5    89.6    94.6    
  53.9      76.6    76.8    77.9    79.9    82.7    86.4    91.0    96.4    
  57.8      76.2    76.6    77.9    80.1    83.3    87.4    92.5    98.4    
  61.7      75.6    76.2    77.8    80.3    83.9    88.5    94.1    100.6   
  65.6      74.9    75.7    77.6    80.6    84.6    89.7    95.8    103.0   
  69.4      74.0    75.1    77.4    80.8    85.3    90.9    97.7    105.5   
  73.3      73.0    74.5    77.1    81.0    86.0    92.3    99.7    108.3   
  77.2      71.8    73.7    76.8    81.2    86.8    93.7    101.8   111.2   
  81.1      70.5    72.8    76.5    81.4    87.7    95.2    104.1   114.2   
  85.0      69.0    71.9    76.1    81.6    88.6    96.8    106.5   117.5
```

These seemed to align with the heat index sample table found on the web using the Fahrenheit scale .  Give that a try.